# Unable to locate Codeigniter DB Session library?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am not sure if anyone as any experience with the Db Session library for Codeigniter but I have been looking all over the internet for a download link and cant seem to find one. On the wiki page it has a link, however when you go to the link it brings you to the standard Codeigniter wiki.

Does anyone have this file they could share or tell me where to get it?

> https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/DB-Session

Comment: read the CI Session Class docs, it's built in

Comment: I thought Codeigniter didnt have built in db sessions? But huge thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a database for session data, it's built into CodeIgniter.

First, create a table to hold the session data:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Here's the SQL from the link above, for your reference:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

Next, in the application/config/config.php file, look for the following sess_use_database config variable and make sure it's set to "TRUE", and, make sure the sess_table_name is set to ci_sessions (or, if you are using a different table name, use that name instead)

```
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
```

After all that is setup, you will be using the database to store your sessions without installing any extra libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I think the library you are looking for is now at:

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/DB2-Session

And why should you be using this rather than DB support of Codeignitor Session library (as explained in DB-session library Git page):

Code Igniter bundles a session class, working with cookies. Unfortunately, this class stores session data directly inside the cookie, thus allowing the client to see and edit those data. Here is a replacement class that stores data in the database.